# Bind to CollectionViewSource in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ViewModel with 2 properties:

- IsReadOnly
- SomeCollectionViewSource

This is a simple working view example:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SomeCollectionViewSource}">
  <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Date}" IsEnabled="False" />      
</StackPanel>
```

Now I want to bind the IsEnabled property:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding}">
  <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=?}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsReadOnly}" />      
</StackPanel>
```

How should the binding look like in this example? (I think I'm mising something simple)
I would prefer a short and easy binding since I have a lot of controls to bind.

Is there a better/easier way to make all controls on one CollectionViewSource read-only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that the above binding targets the current item this should be equivalent:

```
{Binding SomeCollectionViewSource.View/Date}
```

Also see the references for [`Binding.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) and the [PropertyPath syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx) if you have not read them already, there's a lot to it.

The above binding (of your two bindings) is equivalent to:

```
{Binding Path=/Date}
```

The slash can be omitted and if the property is not found on the collection the binding looks for the property on the current item. so...

```
{Binding Date} binds to: CurrentItem -> Date
{Binding Count} binds to: Count
```

For clarity i would suggest always explicity writing the slash.

(*Setting any `DataContext` to `{Binding}` is really pointless by the way*)

Comment: thanks, I learned a lot from this. The empty DataContect binding was only to show the difference. Now I'm just missing the IsReadOnly property on a DatePicker.

Comment: I had to use {Binding SomeCollectionViewSource.View/Date}

Comment: @Roeland: Oh, right, the binding was directly to the source because it is targeted in the property path, if the CollectionViewSource is set as the `Binding.Source` (or DataContext) the bindings will implicity target the `View`, so in those cases the path would just be `/Data`.